# Determining 2 events in a sample space

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory

Consider 2 events $A$ and $B$ in a sample space $S$.

Assume that $\Pr(A) = {1\over 2}$ and $\Pr(B\mid\overline A)= {3\over 5}$. Determine $\Pr(A\cup B)$

Assume that $\Pr(A \cup B) = {5\over 6}$ and $\Pr(\overline A\mid \overline B)={1\over 3}$. Determine $\Pr(B)$.

Comment: Hints: (i) $A\cup B = A \cup (\bar{A} \cap B)$. Can you find $\Pr((\bar{A} \cap B)$ from the given information? (ii) Think DeMorgan's laws.

Answer (score 2):

Write out the formula for conditional probability; that should get you started.

What are $\bar{A}$ and $\bar{B}$?

Comment: So I know that $\overline A$$= 1 -Pr(\overline A) = $$1\over 2$

To get B would it be $Pr(B|\overline A)=$$Pr(B\cap \overline A) \over Pr(B)$$= Pr(\overline A)\over Pr(B)$$= 1/2\over Pr(B)$ 

Since we know that $Pr(B|\overline A) $=$3\over5$ then that would mean that $Pr(B)=$$6\over 5$

Is this looking right?

Comment: @Jimbo Probability can never be greater than $1$.